# Calculation of an integral with square cosine

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, physics, mathematical-physics

How can I calculate this integral? I've already tried changing the variable inside the cosine, calculating by parts and applying trigonometric relationships, but it does not give me the right result.
$$\int_0^Lx^2\cos^2\left(\frac{2\pi x}{L}\right)\,dx$$

Comment: Hint: half angle formula plus parts.

Comment: @SeanRoberson I tried this, but I could not find the result. Could you please post the resolution? I need this integral for a physical test that I have tomorrow, please.

Comment: Please show what you did - you say it does not give you the right result, so if we see it we might be able to say which step you have done wrong.

Comment: @JohnDoe I just deleted what I did because it was wrong. But I can say what I tried to do. First I made a change of variable where $$t = \frac{2\pi x}{L} $$ And then I used the trigonometric formula to make the cosine squarely disappear . Finally, I tried to integrate by parts.

Comment: Just a sanity check, but did you remember to change $dx$ and $L$ (as the limit of integration) as well?

Comment: @AspiringMathematician Yes I changed the limits of integration. I must have fooled myself into some intermediate step. I was grateful that someone would remind me of how it was done. I was very grateful. I have test tomorrow and time is short. Please.

Answer (score 2):

$$I=\int_0^Lx^2\cos^2\frac{2\pi x}{L}\,dx$$
Change variable $x\mapsto \dfrac{tL}{2\pi}$
$$I=\underbrace{\frac{L}{2\pi}}_k\int_0^{2\pi}t^2\cos^2t\,dt$$

$\cos^2 t=\frac12(\cos 2t+1),$ $\int\cos^2 t\,dt=\frac14\sin 2t+\frac12t$

So

$$\begin{align}I&=k\left[t^2\left(\frac14\sin2t+\frac12t\right)\right]_0^{2\pi}-2k\int_0^{2\pi}t\left(\frac14\sin2t+\frac12t\right)\,dt\\
&=k\cdot4\pi^2\cdot\pi-2k\left[t\left(-\frac18\cos 2t+\frac14t^2\right)\right]_0^{2\pi}+2k\int_0^{2\pi}-\frac18\cos 2t+\frac14t^2\,dt\\
&=4k\pi^3-2k\cdot2\pi\cdot\pi^2-2k\cdot2\pi\cdot\left(-\frac18\right)+2k\left[-\frac1{16}\sin2t+\frac1{12}t^3\right]_0^{2\pi}\\
&=\frac43k\pi^3+k\frac\pi2\\&=\frac{L}{2}\left(\frac12+\frac43\pi^2\right)\end{align}$$

Comment: I might have messed up a constant here or there (let me know if you find anything), but I think in general its correct.